# No image using svg-android (Androidify) library

Tags: android, svg, imageview

I'm facing a bad problem with my app using `[svg-android][1]` library. As I asked here:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49755/androidify-does-not-show-correct-graphic-on-my-device

I'm facing the same problem affecting the Androidify app from Google, so I think it's something regarding the loading from resource or the image displaying.

This what I see on my tablet (Android 4.2.2) running Androidify and it's the same bad result I get from my app:

[image: Androidify]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found that in recent version of Android I need to use this code snippet:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
     imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```